# NodeJS send data from stream to FrontEnd(ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, stream

How is going?

How can i send big data(huge request) to FrontEnd? I was extracted data from PostgreSQL, but how response this data to FrontEnd(Json example)? Thx

This my code

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const pool = require('./keys/db');
const QueryStream = require('pg-query-stream')
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream')

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()) 


//starting server
app.listen(PORT,()=>{
console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`)
});

app.get("/to",async(req,res)=>{
try {

    const anyData = await pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const query = new QueryStream(`SELECT"_reference180"."_description" AS person FROM "_reference180"  `)
        const stream = client.query(query)
        //release the client when the stream is finished
        stream.on('end', done)
        stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(process.stdout) // i can see my data in console

    })
    res.send(anyData); // THIS DONT SEND MY DATA, sorry;)
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
}
});
```

Comment: Update as ```        stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res)``` and remove ```res.send(anyData);``` from your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code pipe the result to the console:

```
stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(process.stdout);
```

You have to change your code to pipe the JSON string to the http response:

```
stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
```

Since you have stream the result to the http response, you can remove this line:

```
res.send(anyData);
```